# Custom gestures on iOS. iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, gestures

I am looking to create my own gestures for my iPad app. I know this can be done but don't know where to start. I read that there is some sample code that can store your custom gestures so you can re use them. Think it was as ajson

I'm looking to draw numbers as custom gestures but any sample code/tutorial where I can get an idea where to start I would be very great full!

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Looking for this http://bit.ly/oG0XtS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to start would be the [Event Handling Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH1-SW1) section on [Gesture Recognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html). There's a lot of information there on the different types of gesture recognizers. This should give you enough information on how to create the recognizer(s) that best fits your scenario.